# Python win32com, How to Hide Gridlines

Tags: python-2.7, win32com, gridlines

Is there a way to hide gridlines in a sheet excel 2007 using `win32com.client` and Python? I've been looking through MSDN and there's a gridline Object under excel, but it only refers to hiding gridlines in a chart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835311(v=office.15).aspx

Code I am using for testing is:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Active
sheet.DisplayGridLines == False
```

There's no property `DisplayGridLines`.

I'm sort of new to using the MSDN site, so maybe I am not searching through it properly and it's quite possible, `win32com` can't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I finally came across the solution. Grab the Active Window after setting the sheet object and setting 'DisplayGridlines' to False:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)

excel.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
```